# <input> form elements work in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble with **input** form elements in an ASP.NET MVC app.  The "Add" and "Remove" input buttons work properly in Chrome, but not in IE.

We're using IE 11 and Chrome 66

- In Chrome, when I click the Add or Remove button, the MVC Action is definitely executed
- In IE, when I click either of these buttons, it seems that the View is just re-loaded.
- The "Cancel" button (which just returns the user to the homepage) works fine in both browsers.

Here is the rendered HTML:

```html
<form action="/MyController/ActionWindow" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="[TOKEN]" />    
    <table width="80%">
        <tr align="left">
            <th>
                Desired Action:
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td width="100">
                            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="/MyController/AddItem" value="Add Group" name="Add" id="submit" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="100">
                            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="/MyController/RemoveItem" value="Remove Group" name="Remove" id="submit" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="100">
                            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel();" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code looks right to me...and formaction is supported in IE 10+, have you tried removing the anti-forgery token, to make sure that is not causing any problem?

Comment: The Controller name in action may not contain the word `Controller`. Can you try changing the action as `/My/ActionWindow` ? This cannot be browser dependent but no harm in trying.

Comment: Try to  use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error?

Comment: the 2 buttons have the same id (id="submit") could this be the issue?

Comment: @SergiuMuresan - Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried assigning separate IDs to the input elements, but the behavior was still the same.